# How do I add images to a slideshow using Ajax from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have created a slideshow using JQUERY but can't add images via HTML. I'm supposed to use AJAX to add the pictures from a JSON file. How can I do this? I looked
HTML Code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Assignment 4 - COMP_122</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
            <div class="gallery-outer">
                <img src="images/arrow-left.png" class="previous" alt="Previous">
                <div class="gallery-inner">
                    <!-- <img src="Images/1.jpg" width="500px" height="300px" class="image 
                    active">
                    <img src="Images/2.jpg" width="500px" height="300px" class="image">
                    <img src="Images/3.jpg" width="500px" height="300px" class="image">
                    <img src="Images/4.jpg" width="500px" height="300px" class="image">
                    <img src="Images/5.jpg" width="500px" height="300px" class="image"> -->
                </div>
                <img src="images/arrow-right.png" class="next" alt="Next">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JS Code:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhttp.onreadstatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 & this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("gallery-inner")
```

JSON for Images

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Hydrangeas",
    "description": "Display for 3.5 seconds",
    "source": "Images/1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jellyfish",
    "description": "Display for 3.5 seconds",
    "source": "Images/2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Koala",
    "description": "Display for 3.5 seconds",
    "source": "Images/3.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Penguins",
    "description": "Display for 3.5 seconds",
    "source": "Images/4.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Tulips",
    "description": "Display for 3.5 seconds",
    "source": "Images/5.jpg"
  }]
```

I know the JS code is incomplete... I just don't know how to proceed. How can I use AJAX to add the JSON file to the page while also maintaining the slideshow functionality?

Comment: Your question seems strange at best, mostly because you don't need AJAX to request images. You simply need a HTTP request for that image/s and you're done.

Comment: Also, stating that you need to fetch some JSON file, without showing the JSON data and explaining the peculiarities, will make it hard to guess what's exactly happening.